# Join URLs for redirect using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have URL as string like this in jquery function:

```
var url="https://linksredirect.com/?pub_id=9551CL8805&url=http%3A//http://www.paytm.com";
```

and want to redirect page at above full URL using

```
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

but it goes to http://http//www.paytm.com

Comment: How are you joining the URLs, add complete code

Comment: its string of urls

Comment: `var url = "https://linksredirect.com/?pub_id=9551CL8805&url=" + encodeURIComponent('http://www.paytm.com');`

Comment: @Tushar it works fine for redirect

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `:` with `%3A`, it must be escaped so as the URL would be valid. Also, replace the slashes with `%2F` and remove extra `http%3A`.

```
var url="https://linksredirect.com/?pub_id=9551CL8805&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.paytm.com";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

---

If the last part of path is dynamic, you may want to use `encodeURIComponent` to encode it.

Comment: The issue is not location.href I only can use location=url and it works

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Look at the beginning of my answer, does it work with this?

Comment: In my original string there is no %2E

Comment: @Muhammad Read my second sentence, those are the encoded dots.

Comment: @nicael There is extra `http%3A//` after `url=`. Removing that should work.

Comment: @Muhammad Sorry, there was another mistake. Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Tushar recommendation:

```
var url = "https://linksredirect.com/?pub_id=9551CL8805&url=" + encodeURIComponent('http://www.paytm.com');
```

works fine for redirect.